# How to merge arrays of different objects in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, higher-order-functions

It sounds simple, but how can I merge two arrays of different types (Simpson & Movie) in Swift, then go on to order that array of objects alphabetically by their only common property - in this case 'name'?

```
struct Simpson {
    var age: Int
    var name: String
    init(age: Int, name: String) {
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
    }
}
let homer = Simpson(age: 39, name: "Homer")
let marge = Simpson(age: 36, name: "Marge")
var simpson = [homer, marge] // [{age 39, name "Homer"}, {age 36, name "Marge"}]

struct Movie {
    var location: String
    var name: String
    init(location: String, name: String) {
        self.location = location
        self.name = name
    }
}
let jaws = Movie(location: "Amity", name: "Jaws")
let et = Movie(location: "LA", name: "E.T")
var movies: [Movie] = [jaws, et] // [{location "Amity", name "Jaws"}, {location "LA", name "E.T"}]
```

Comment: The answer that @Sh_Khan gave is (in my opinion) better and more Swifty than the accepted answer in the linked question, just by the way

Comment: @Sam, sure, but the top voted answer in the linked question covers it.

Comment: @vacawama True, but it's not the best solution to use (again, imo)

Comment: @Sam, how is Sh_Khan's answer different than CodeDifferent's?  They both use a protocol to unite the types, add the common property to that protocol, create an array of that protocol type, and sort that array based upon the common property.

Comment: @vacawama That's true, it's not. But that's not the answer that would be seen by going to the other question.

Comment: @Sam, it's smart to consider all answers.  The *accepted answer* was preferred by a single user.  That certainly doesn't make it a better answer than the others *especially* one that has a higher vote count.

Comment: @vacawama I agree, but I know some people who would not read beyond the accepted answer; so I pointed out that I though an answer that was not accepted was better

Comment: @Mississippi, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32976103/1630618) is the one you want from the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
protocol SharedName {
    var name : String {get set}
}

struct Simpson: SharedName {
    var name : String = ""
    // add other vars 
}

struct Movie: SharedName {
    var name : String = ""
    // add other vars 
}
```

Then create an array of

```
var arr:[SharedName] = [] // fill in with different objects from Simpson and Movie
arr.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

---

**Tip:**

With `struct` get rid of `init`

```
init(age: Int, name: String) {
    self.age = age
    self.name = name
}
```

&

```
init(location: String, name: String) {
    self.location = location
    self.name = name
}
```

It's supposed that you'll get them generated automatically